# How to add contacts into Calendar using Redemption.dll ? using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am using below code:

Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem   objAppointment;

Redemption.RDORecurrencePattern objRecurrence;

objAppointment = (Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem)p_objDestFolder.Items.Add(
                 p_objDestFolder.DefaultItemType);

objAppointment.OptionalAttendees = "Contact@yahoo.com";

objAppointment.RequiredAttendees = "Contact@stack.com;

objAppointment.Save();

But above code not adding contact into Caledar.

Can anyone help me out in it.

Regards,

Saggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I am currently using to schedule an appointment:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
session.Logon(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false, true, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false);

RDOFolder calendar = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

RDOAppointmentItem oAppointment = (RDOAppointmentItem)calendar.Items.Add(rdoItemType.olAppointmentItem);

oAppointment.Subject = "This is a test subject";
oAppointment.Body = "This is a test body";
oAppointment.Start = DateTime.Now;
oAppointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
oAppointment.ReminderSet = true;
oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30;
oAppointment.Importance = (int)rdoImportance.olImportanceNormal;
oAppointment.BusyStatus = rdoBusyStatus.olBusy;

oAppointment.Save();

oAppointment = null;
calendar = null;
session.Logoff();
session = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using Redemption should not make a difference:
Use `AppointmentItem.Recipients.Add()` to add recipients.
To set them as optional or required (default) set the recipient type to `olRequired` or `olOptional` (see `OlMeetingRecipientType` in the Object Browser in Outlooks Macro Editor).

Examples:
`Recipients.Item(1).Type = olRequired`
`Recipients.Add("foo@bar.com").Type = olOptional`